# Can we make Oracle return error immediately after tablespace corruption

Tags: database, oracle

I have developed an Oracle pro*C/C++ library that provides an API to other applications to read data from database tables and insert/update data in the tables. Recently a customer reported that the API did not return any error when underlying file systems (ASM) that hold tables spaces went down for a few days! This must be due to caching data by Oracle instance.

My question is this: Can we make Oracle return error, without affecting its caching scheme, for any read/write access to a table immediately after its table space is found to be not accessible due to corruption or any disk related errors?

I did a small experiment to simulate the customer's problem. I have created a new directory on my Linux system. Created a table space in it and created a table to use the table space. Inserted a few rows using sqlplus and fetched rows from the table and verified results. They are OK. Then I renamed table space file to some other file to simulate missing/corruption  of the table space. Oracle still returned rows even though physical table space was missing. I could even insert a few rows successfully and commit went through without any error(probably this may fail for large number of inserts).  However, I could not shut down the database instance. Once I aborted the instance, start up failed with an error saying the table space could not be identified/locked. After that sqlplus could not connect to the database. But my requirement is to get an error for any DML operation if the table space file found to be missing or corrupted.

Following is my experiment:

1. Created a directory for a new tablespace

   ```
   [root@mvsLTOraLin u01]# mkdir /orats
   [root@mvsLTOraLin u01]# chown oracle /orats
   [root@mvsLTOraLin u01]# chgrp oinstall /orats
   ```
2. Created a table space using sysdba user as following:

   ```
   SQL> create tablespace orats datafile '/orats/ots1.dbf' size 5M;

   Tablespace created.

   [root@mvsLTOraLin orats]# pwd
   /orats
   [root@mvsLTOraLin orats]# ls -l
   total 5128
   -rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall 5251072 Jul 11 17:53 ots1.dbf
   ```
3. Created a table in the table space using fis_admin user and inserted 3 rows:

   ```
   -bash-4.1$ sqlplus fis_admin/fis_admin@fisdb

   SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Jul 11 17:56:50 2015

   Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


   Connected to:
   Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
   With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

   SQL> create table tbl1(c1 int not null primary key, c2 varchar2(100)) tablespace orats;

   Table created.

   SQL> insert into tbl1 values(1, 'one');

   1 row created.

   SQL> insert into tbl1 values(2, 'two');

   1 row created.

   SQL> insert into tbl1 values(3, 'three');

   1 row created.


   SQL> select * from tbl1;

       C1
   ----------
   C2
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1
   one

        2
   two

        3
   three
   ```
4. Renamed table space file from `ots1.dbf` to `gone.dbf` to simulate corruption of the table space.

   ```
   [root@mvsLTOraLin orats]# date
   Sat Jul 11 18:03:00 IST 2015
   [root@mvsLTOraLin orats]# mv ots1.dbf gone.dbf
   [root@mvsLTOraLin orats]# ls -l
   total 5128
   -rw-r-----. 1 oracle oinstall 5251072 Jul 11 17:53 gone.dbf
   ```
5. Selected data from sqlplus which is still connected

   ```
   SQL> select c1, current_timestamp from tbl1;

       C1
   ----------
   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1
   11-JUL-15 06.05.20.525276 PM +05:30

        2
   11-JUL-15 06.05.20.525276 PM +05:30

        3
   11-JUL-15 06.05.20.525276 PM +05:30
   ```

   Retrieved data even though table-space disappeared. 
   This shows Oracle is returning from its cache.
6. Restarted sqlplus and queried. Still server did not realise that its table space is missing!

   ```
   SQL> quit
   Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
   With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
   -bash-4.1$ 
   -bash-4.1$ sqlplus fis_admin/fis_admin@fisdb

   SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Jul 11 18:07:24 2015

   Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


   Connected to:
   Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
   With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

   SQL> select c1, current_timestamp from tbl1;

       C1
   ----------
   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1
   11-JUL-15 06.07.42.014083 PM +05:30

        2
   11-JUL-15 06.07.42.014083 PM +05:30

        3
   11-JUL-15 06.07.42.014083 PM +05:30
   ```
7. Tried to shutdown the instance

   ```
   -bash-4.1$ sqlplus / as sysdba

   SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Sat Jul 11 18:08:42 2015

   Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


   Connected to:
   Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
   With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

   SQL> shutdown
   ORA-01116: error in opening database file 5
   ORA-01110: data file 5: '/orats/ots1.dbf'
   ORA-27041: unable to open file
   Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
   Additional information: 3
   SQL>
   ```

It failed as expected.

8. Tried to insert a row.

   ```
   SQL> insert into tbl1 values(4, 'four');

   1 row created.
   ```

   Surprise! The insert was successful. It must may fail for many inserts.
9. Forced shutdown

   ```
   SQL> shutdown
   ORA-01116: error in opening database file 5
   ORA-01110: data file 5: '/orats/ots1.dbf'
   ORA-27041: unable to open file
   Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
   Additional information: 3
   SQL> shutdown immediate
   ORA-01116: error in opening database file 5
   ORA-01110: data file 5: '/orats/ots1.dbf'
   ORA-27041: unable to open file
   Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
   Additional information: 3
   SQL> shutdown abort
   ORACLE instance shut down.
   SQL> quit
   ```
10. Restarted instance

    ```
    SQL> startup;
    ORACLE instance started.

    Total System Global Area 1068937216 bytes
    Fixed Size          2220200 bytes
    Variable Size         742395736 bytes
    Database Buffers      318767104 bytes
    Redo Buffers            5554176 bytes
    Database mounted.
    ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 5 - see DBWR trace file
    ORA-01110: data file 5: '/orats/ots1.dbf'
    ```

    Error is shown as expected.
11. Tried access to tbl1:

    ```
    SQL> select c1, current_timestamp from tbl1;
    select c1, current_timestamp from tbl1
                                      *
    ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only
    ```

Failed as expected.

So, is there a way to make Oracle return error on next access to the table for reading or writing even though data may be returned from cache?

Comment: What you are describing does not appear to be related to Oracle (I have no idea whether this is really what the customer is complaining about).  In most (all?) Unix operating systems, if you rename a file, a program that has opened the file still has access to it.  Oracle isn't caching anything here, it's simply using the existing file handle.  That doesn't go away until Oracle is forced to close the handle.  Oracle can't report anything because as far as it and the operating system are concerned, it's still reading from a valid file handle.

Comment: You can verify that it was still using the renamed file by checking the modified time on the `gone.dbf` file, which will show the shutdown time (roughly, but 18:08 or later) rather than the time it had when you renamed it, 17:53.

Comment: @Alex Poole: Do you mean verify using file system API such as [f]open(), [f]read, etc.? If so, yes, this is one method of checking if all table space files are accessible and if not return error to the application immediately. At certain intervals, program can keep checking to make sure physical database files are OK. But I do not want application to do this because I do not know if this is a good idea for any apps to bypass the database system to check if something maintained by the database systems is OK! I want to know if Oracle Database provides any API for checking table space integrity.

Comment: @mvsagar - no, I was referring to what Justin said, just using `ls -l` as part of your test; which will demonstrate why it's fatally flawed. But I think you're chasing shadows here. I don't believe what your client reported could be down to the DB. I'm not going to kill an ASM instance to test it, but I'd expect a matter of seconds at most between ASM dying, or any real physical issue or corruption (force unmounting perhaps), and Oracle throwing errors and making it eeally obvious something is wrong. If your API is caching data that's not a DB issue. If you queried the DB you'd see the errors.

Comment: @Alex poole- The app does not have any caching scheme. Many database inserts went through without an error from Oracle. In my experiment, when I gave an SQL stmt to get all rows from a table, then select failed as expected. But SELECTs which referred to rows in Oracle cache (I assume) ran successfully. The machine running the app at customer site has about 100GB of RAM. In fact my client reported that oracle logs contained errors from ASM and related Oracle replication services failed due to ASM failures.

Comment: ASM errors aren't the same as ASM being down, which is what you implied. ASM is [designed to have redundancy](https://blogs.oracle.com/ODA/entry/asm_normal_redundancy_versus_high), and errors do not always mean problems would be visible to the DB. I doubt your application is supposed to monitor the storage state too. Maybe you need to be more specific about the issues that were seen. And you haven't shown an error from selecting all rows in your experiment - querying all the rows in step 6 looks OK. But that's a moot point as whatever your client saw, you are not replicating it with this test.